# Issues getting a center navbar on bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am currently trying to build a website using bootstrap, it is a very basic website, I am trying to setup the homepage where it has a carousel of images and am having issues setting up the navbar. I can't seem to get a floating centered navbar that includes the logo. I want to use the logo as a href to the homepage and then have a button labeled photos that will have a dropdown menu for the photos and a contact page that will have an anchor section on the homepage. I have worked with bootstrap previously but not to an extent that I feel 100% comfortable. I have managed to make use of various stack overflow forums for my other issues but have been having issues figuring out how to do this.

Below is the gist of my navbar code.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
        <title>blah</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/carousel/">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <style>
          .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
          }

          @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
              font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
          }
          .headerrow {

          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 5%;
          padding-bottom: 5%;
          }
          img.caro {
            width: 140;
            height: 140;
          }
        </style>
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="logo2.png" style="width:8%; height:8%;"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main">

      <div class="container">
        <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="border-radius: 15px; width:100%; height: 600px !important;">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="cover.jpg" alt="Cover1" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="cover2.jpg" alt="Cover2" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="LogChimneyOut.jpg" alt="Cover3" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="Fireplace3.jpg" alt="Cover3" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="Deck1.jpg" alt="Cover3" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="Wall2.jpg" alt="Cover3" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="Fireplace2.jpg" alt="Cover3" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This includes the navbar as well as the carousel image slideshow right below it. I am trying to get a floating center navbar right on top of the carousel that has the logo, pictures button, and contact page. I have looked elsewhere for navbars but the always seem to break the carousel section. I am most certainly not the greatest with HTML or bootstrap but I am trying here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `navbar-nav` menu, create a new list item and move the `a` tag that hold your logo image inside it, and finally replace `mr-auto` class with `mx-auto`,`align-items-center` classes to make all items centered.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto align-items-center">
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="nav-link"><img src=".." alt="..">logo</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins) how the **flexbox alignment** works in BS4

For the [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/) menu button, follow this structure:

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown_id" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photos</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_id">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Photos</a>
   </div>
</li>
```

> Please note that in your snippet you have linked unnecessarily
>   different versions of Bootstrap files. Follow this [introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)
>   to see how to include Bootstrap properly in your website.

**Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto align-items-md-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50&text=logo" alt="logo" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photos</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Photo</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main role="main">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/1100x400" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="400" class="w-100 h-100">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/1100x400" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="400" class="w-100 h-100">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="//source.unsplash.com/random/1100x400" alt="New York" width="1100" height="400" class="w-100 h-100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I just went through and cleaned up the stylesheets, now I just need to tweak the carousel a bit to get it how I want it in the center with the next and previous still on the pictures versus on the edge of the window. Thanks!